# Base64 decoding in Python 3.2 type error

Tags: python

```
def make(key):
    key = base64.b64decode(key)
```

When I run this function, I get a type error in this line.

What's going on?

Comment: Post the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Psychic debugging: You probably passed a `str` object to the function, but `base64.b64decode` requires a `bytes` object.  So, you'll need to encode the string.

```
key = base64.b64decode(key.encode('ASCII'))
```

Note that [Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#base64) is more lenient and lets you pass either `str` or `bytes`.

Comment: then call key = base64.b64decode(key.encode('ASCII')). I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    base64.b64decode(key.encode('ASCII'))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\base64.py", line 92, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Thanks.